# Parsing JS JSON to Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, json

So I'm working on a small project that involves scraping a forum for data(not spammy).

I have an issue with a JS JSON array, I'm not sure how to make it readable in ruby.

Here's a example of what I'm pulling from the forum.

```
\n    //<!--\n            require([\"main\"], function() {\n            require([\"PoE/Item/DeferredItemRenderer\"], function(R) { (new R([[0,{\"verified\":false,\"w\":2,\"h\":3,\"icon\":\"http:\\/\\/webcdn.pathofexile.com\\/image\\/Art\\/2DItems\\/Armours\\/BodyArmours\\/BodyStrDexInt1C.png?scale=1&v=5a4eb9d863bef835aa3d9cc9224f51a51\",\"support\":true,\"league\":\"Hardcore\",\"sockets\":[{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"S\"},{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"I\"},{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"S\"},{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"I\"},{\"group\":1,\"attr\":\"D\"},{\"group\":2,\"attr\":\"I\"}],\"name\":\"Corruption Ward\",\"typeLine\":\"Vaal Regalia\",\"identified\":true,\"properties\":[{\"name\":\"Quality\",\"values\":[[\"+20%\",1]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Energy Shield\",\"values\":[[\"605\",1]],\"displayMode\":0}],\"requirements\":[{\"name\":\"Level\",\"values\":[[\"68\",0]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Int\",\"values\":[[\"194\",0]],\"displayMode\":1}],\"explicitMods\":[\"+50 to Intelligence\",\"60% increased Energy Shield\",\"+140 to maximum Energy Shield\"],\"frameType\":2,\"socketedItems\":[]},[]],[1,{\"verified\":true,\"w\":2,\"h\":2,\"icon\":\"http:\\/\\/webcdn.pathofexile.com\\/image\\/Art\\/2DItems\\/Armours\\/Helmets\\/HelmetInt4.png?scale=1&v=0f230458eaf985d877912eae780a91fc1\",\"support\":true,\"league\":\"Hardcore\",\"sockets\":[{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"D\"},{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"S\"},{\"group\":1,\"attr\":\"I\"},{\"group\":1,\"attr\":\"I\"}],\"name\":\"Dusk Visage\",\"typeLine\":\"Royal Circlet\",\"identified\":true,\"properties\":[{\"name\":\"Quality\",\"values\":[[\"+20%\",1]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Energy Shield\",\"values\":[[\"261\",1]],\"displayMode\":0}],\"requirements\":[{\"name\":\"Level\",\"values\":[[\"65\",0]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Int\",\"values\":[[\"138\",0]],\"displayMode\":1}],\"explicitMods\":[\"+22 to Intelligence\",\"43% increased Energy Shield\",\"+61 to maximum Energy Shield\",\"22% increased Rarity of Items found\",\"+20% to Fire Resistance\",\"14% increased Block and Stun Recovery\"],\"frameType\":2,\"socketedItems\":[]},[]],[2,{\"verified\":false,\"w\":2,\"h\":3,\"icon\":\"http:\\/\\/webcdn.pathofexile.com\\/image\\/Art\\/2DItems\\/Armours\\/Shields\\/ShieldStrInt5.png?scale=1&v=823818e9cfc86e3ea4c642b97695932c1\",\"support\":true,\"league\":\"Hardcore\",\"sockets\":[{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"S\"},{\"group\":1,\"attr\":\"I\"},{\"group\":2,\"attr\":\"I\"}],\"name\":\"Cataclysm Rock\",\"typeLine\":\"Angelic Kite Shield\",\"identified\":true,\"properties\":[{\"name\":\"Quality\",\"values\":[[\"+20%\",1]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Chance to Block\",\"values\":[[\"24%\",0]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Armour\",\"values\":[[\"322\",1]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Energy Shield\",\"values\":[[\"324\",1]],\"displayMode\":0}],\"requirements\":[{\"name\":\"Level\",\"values\":[[\"55\",0]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Str\",\"values\":[[\"70\",0]],\"displayMode\":1},{\"name\":\"Int\",\"values\":[[\"70\",0]],\"displayMode\":1}],\"implicitMods\":[\"+24% to all Elemental Resistances\"],\"explicitMods\":[\"108% increased Armour and Energy Shield\",\"+92 to maximum Energy Shield\",\"+37% to Cold Resistance\",\"+7% to Lightning Resistance\",\"12% increased Block and Stun Recovery\"],\"frameType\":2,\"socketedItems\":[]},[]],[3,{\"verified\":true,\"w\":2,\"h\":1,\"icon\":\"http:\\/\\/webcdn.pathofexile.com\\/image\\/Art\\/2DItems\\/Belts\\/Belt1.png?scale=1&v=a40ff49a65beb9e722af0f85159432f11\",\"support\":true,\"league\":\"Hardcore\",\"sockets\":[],\"name\":\"Rage Snare\",\"typeLine\":\"Rustic Sash\",\"identified\":true,\"requirements\":[{\"name\":\"Level\",\"values\":[[\"39\",0]],\"displayMode\":0}],\"implicitMods\":[\"21% increased Physical Damage\"],\"explicitMods\":[\"+19 to maximum Energy Shield\",\"+32% to Fire Resistance\",\"+15% to Cold Resistance\",\"+31% to Lightning Resistance\"],\"frameType\":2,\"socketedItems\":[]},[]],[4,{\"verified\":false,\"w\":2,\"h\":2,\"icon\":\"http:\\/\\/webcdn.pathofexile.com\\/image\\/Art\\/2DItems\\/Armours\\/Gloves\\/MaligarosVirtousity.png?scale=1&v=2614d1663cda7c88fa4b600c03cbc42a1\",\"support\":true,\"league\":\"Hardcore\",\"sockets\":[{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"S\"},{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"D\"},{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"I\"},{\"group\":0,\"attr\":\"I\"}],\"name\":\"Maligaro's Virtuosity\",\"typeLine\":\"Deerskin Gloves\",\"identified\":true,\"properties\":[{\"name\":\"Quality\",\"values\":[[\"+20%\",1]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Evasion Rating\",\"values\":[[\"121\",1]],\"displayMode\":0}],\"requirements\":[{\"name\":\"Level\",\"values\":[[\"21\",0]],\"displayMode\":0},{\"name\":\"Dex\",\"values\":[[\"33\",0]],\"displayMode\":1}],\"explicitMods\":[\"+23 to Dexterity\",\"5% increased Attack Speed\",\"50% increased Global Critical Strike Chance\",\"41% increased Global Critical Strike Multiplier\",\"63% increased Evasion Rating\"],\"flavourText\":[\"Maligaro operated effortlessly,\\r\",\"with great speed and terrible consequences.\"],\"frameType\":3,\"socketedItems\":[]},[]]])).run(); });\n        });    //-->\n"
```

Comment: Why are _random_ characters escaped? (notably: newlines and `"`)

Comment: @FritsvanCampen the escaping is not random; it's pretty uniform.  Someone's created a JSON string of a JSON string of an object - it's been marshalled twice.

Comment: I don't know what that is. JSON can't start with a `\ `. Allowed starting characters are `{ [ " -`. JSON also doesn't do functions, so if this is encoded twice, decoding it not going to work. Check http://json.org/

Comment: Whatever that is it's not JSON - it looks like Javascript code that some sort of AJAX support library is meant to evaluate directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost-valid JSON code in your string, but the quotes in it are escaped, and it's wrapped up inside some JavaScript code that uses that JSON data.

If you strip away the JavaScript code and unescape the quotes you can parse the JSON. You can do that with a few regular expressions.

Assuming your test data is in a file called `download.txt`, this code will do it:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'

input = File.read( 'download.txt' )

a = input.gsub( /[\r\n]/m, '' )  # Remove newlines
b = a.gsub( /\\"/, '"' )         # Unescape quotes
c = b.sub( /^.*\(new R\(/, '' )  # Remove JavaScript at beginning
d = c.sub( /\)\)\.run.*$/, '' )  # Remove JavaScript at end

j = JSON.parse( d )  # Now we have JSON we can parse

p j.class   # Prints Array
p j.length  # Prints 5
p j         # Prints JSON data
```